# Fluid image adapts size according to screen size

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<img src="https://www.sporedev.ro/pleiade/images/Maya.jpg" class="full-img">
<img src="https://www.sporedev.ro/pleiade/cufar.png" class="treasure treasure-maya">
```

And the following CSS:

```
.full-img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100vh;  
}
.treasure{
height: 125px;
width:  120px;
} 

.treasure-maya{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 55%; 
    left: 44%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The reason why I use `img` instead of the CSS much simpler method, `background-image`, is because the image is being used as an image map.

[Here is a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5xnfmeLp/)

[Here is a link to my live project.](https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/maya2.html)

I tried adapting the `.treasure` image to the `.full-img` so that, when the `.full-img` is reducing in size, the `.treasure` image keeps its position and ratio.

I managed to find a solution, using media queries, but it's really counter-productive because I'd have to take into account **a lot** of different resolutions. I already added three media queries and that only takes care of **some** of the resolutions that I'd need to take into account (probably around 20 media queries).

I looked on Google and SO for a solution for my problem but I couldn't find an answer.

What I'd need, is to somehow make the `.treasure img` reduce in size together with the `.full-img img`.

Is this achievable?

If there's a way to do this in CSS I'd prefer that. If not, I guess that JS would be the only way to do it but, unfortunately, I'm a novice when it comes to JS.

Comment: Why don't you just make the width of the treasure image using percents(%)? Also your main image does not keep its ratio when resizing

Comment: Because that would stretch it across the whole screen, totally opposite from what I want.

Comment: Why would it stretch it across the whole screen? Your image is positioned absolutely, it would stay where it is now except the width will be in percentage instead of fixed width

Comment: Because of the way percentages work. It will try to fit 100% of the screen. Please open the JSFiddle that I linked in the question and try to set the height and the width of the treasure class to 100% and you'll see the result.

Comment: I never said to set it to 100% and I don't see why you would set it to 100%, it doesn't make any sense. Just set it to 15% or something like that. I already tried before I commented

Comment: Sorry, you were right. This solved my problems. I thought that percentages work a little differently. Seems that I overcomplicated the problem myself. Please post it as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set image width using percentage instead of fixed width. I have removed the height for the image so the ratio is kept but you can change this if you need to

For example

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.full-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.treasure {
  width: 15%;
}

.treasure-maya {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 44%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is the background image (I can't implement it in the CSS way because I use it together with <map> in my app ) -->
<img src="https://www.sporedev.ro/pleiade/images/Maya.jpg" class="full-img">

<!-- This is the image that needs to reduce its height and width, according to the full-img reduction -->
<img src="https://www.sporedev.ro/pleiade/cufar.png" class="treasure treasure-maya">
```

Comment: Don't you think the image might look deteriorated if you force both the width and height without setting either to "auto".

Comment: For the main image? Yes it won't retain image ratio but that's how the OP has it and I assume it is for a reason